# create shortcode to list users with specific meta key value

Tags: functions, shortcode, users, user-roles, user-meta

I have a function that I use to list users within a specific role, that match a specific meta key value. It works when I use it directly on the page ---

```
<?php 
$bmail = $current_user->user_email;
   $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'broker_email', 'meta_value' => $bmail,  'fields' => 'all'  ) );
   $users = $user_query->get_results();

  if (!empty($users)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($users as $user){
        echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  } else {
    echo 'No users found';
  };
?>
```

But when I try to create as a shortcode --

```
function thebroker_agents() {
  global $current_user;
$bmail = $current_user->user_email;
   $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'broker_email', 'meta_value' => $bmail,  'fields' => 'all'  ) );
   $users = $user_query->get_results();
  if (!empty($users)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($users as $user){
        echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  } else {
    echo 'No users found';
  }
// Adds the above function as as shortcode
add_shortcode( 'your_agents', 'thebroker_agents' );
```

And call on the same page like so --

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[your_agents]'); ?>
```

It doesn't do anything except echo out the text - "[your_agents]"

What am I doing wrong with my shortcode function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function thebroker_agents() {
    global $current_user;
    $bmail = $current_user->user_email;
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'broker_email', 'meta_value' => $bmail,  'fields' => 'all'  ) );
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    if (!empty($users)) {
        $results = '<ul>';
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $results = '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
        }
        $results =  '</ul>';
    } else {
        $results =  'No users found';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $results;
}
// Adds the above function as as shortcode
add_shortcode( 'your_agents', 'thebroker_agents' );
```

You were missing a last bracket.  Also I changed the code a bit from echoing, to returning your results.  I also reset your post data.  Not sure why you didn't use a while statement in your code, but left that alone.

Since you are calling your function in php, you don't need a short code.  you can call it just like this:

```
echo thebroker_agents();
```

However your echo do shortcode will still work as well.

Comment: the return - $results line gave me a error so I had to remove the "=" sign. After doing so it still didnt work. @rudtek

Comment: yep, equal sign was a mistake.  What didn't work though?  Can you tell me the error?

Comment: Without the equal sign it didnt show no error, it didnt show anything.

Comment: should be working. Try with new updates above.  Do you have debug on?  Maybe a log issue?

Comment: what did you change? It seems to be working now only when viewing the page as a admin. The code is suppose to display when a admin or user with my custom "broker" role views the page.

Comment: Im not sure why your answer didnt work 100% for me but I decided to just do it directly on my page. Thanks.